# Loader.loadPDF didn't load Image from PDF/1A correkt / fully

Tags: java, pdfbox

```
PDDocument document = Loader.loadPDF(pdfDokument);
for (int pageIndex = 0; pageIndex < document.getNumberOfPages(); ++pageIndex) {
var bim = ConvertPdfToImageUtil.pageConvertToImage(document.getPage(pageIndex), 300, ImageType.RGB);
      ImageIO.write(bim, "png", new File(  "test.png"));

public static BufferedImage pageConvertToImage(PDPage page, int dpi, ImageType imageType) throws IOException {

        try (PDDocument document = new PDDocument()) {
            document.addPage(page);
            PDFRenderer renderer = new PDFRenderer(document);
            document.close();
            return renderer.renderImageWithDPI(0, dpi, imageType);
        }
    }
```

What is the problem with loading the pdf-a and converting it to a BufferedImage?
I can only see individual characters of the pdf document?

[image]

Comment: I don't have your PDF, so I cannot test. One thing is weird, though, in your code: In `pageConvertToImage` you create `renderer` based on `document`, then close `document`, and then use `renderer`. As using `renderer` requires access to the underlying `document`, this is likely to cause issues.

Comment: Your previous question was closed while pointing to code showing how to render PDFs. Please use that code. Watch for log messages. Don't disable logging. Or try to display the PDF with PDFDebugger.